# Firebase Atmonic Add and delete entry

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have the following data structure in my firebase

```
-ActionSheet
    -PendingApproval 
        -SomeKey1
            -someData
            -someData
            -someData
        -SomeKey2
            -someData
            -someData
            -someData
    -Approved
        -SomeKey3
            -someData
            -someData
            -someData
```

The user is displayed with all the items in pendingApproval when the screen appears. 
When the user clicks approve on one of the entry, I want to move the data from "PendingApproval" to "Approved" node.

Say if the user clicked approved for SomeKey1, Currently, I am doing it the following way

```
1. Duplicate the data to Approved node 

2. Upon success, delete the entry SomeKey1 from PendingApproval
```

However, there is a small chance that step one succeeded and step two failed. In this case I would have two SomeKey1 in my database

I was wondering if there is a way to do this atomatically such that the operation is guaranteed to succeed or fail at the same time.

I have just read [Firebase Atmoic](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) and they only mentioned atomic update as oppose to "set + remove".

Below is my code

```
// save data to firebase
saveoFirebase_approved(myData: Object, key: string) {
    let savePath = '/ActionSheet/Approved/' + key;
    return this.af.database.object(savePath).set(myData);
}

// remove pending approval from firebase
removePendingFromFirebase(myData: Object) {
    let savePath = '/ActionSheet/PendingApproval/' + key;
    return this.af.database.object(savePath).remove();
}


this.databaseService.saveoFirebase_approved(data, key)
  .then(result => {

    // delete pending from firebase
    this.databaseService.removePendingFromFirebase(data)
      .then(result => {
        // both action completed
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // something went wrong deleting item from firebase
      })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // something went wrong saving to firebase
  })
 }
```

Note: I am using Angular 2 with AngularFire

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete data in a multi-location update by setting `null` to the location. So your operation then becomes:

```
var updates = {
  'PendingApproval/SomeKey1': null,
  'Approved/SomeKey1': {
    SomeDate: 'Value'
  }
};
ref.child("ActionSheet").update(updates);
```

You could even validate in your security rules that data can only be written to `Approved` if it was previously pending and is now no longer pending:

```
"Approved": {
  "$key": {
    ".write": "data.parent().parent().child('PendingApprocal').child($key).exists()
        && !newData.parent().parent().child('PendingApprocal').child($key).exists()"
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Seems like there is no way to do it with angular fire but it is just as easy to integrate this to my app. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for whats called a transaction I believe.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

Comment: I have never used transaction before. But after looking at the documentations, it does not seem like this would be the way to go for?  As I am not "Working with data that could be corrupted by concurrent modifications, such as incremental counters, you can use a transaction operation." (from the doc). I have also updated the question with my code to help illustrate the need abit better. Cheers